# Print a word 10 times in Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I need to print a word 10 times in assembly but my code in a previous version of the question only prints 1 time.

Also, how can I remove the null bytes?

This is a fixed version that does print 10 times, if built into a static executable so the high bytes of EAX are zero before this code runs.

```
section .text
global _start       ;must be declared for using gcc
_start:                     ;tell linker entry point
mov si,10
l1:
mov dl, len    ;message length
mov ecx, msg    ;message to write
mov bl, 1       ;file descriptor (stdout)
mov al, 4       ;system call number (sys_write)
int 0x80        ;call kernel
dec si
JNZ l1         
mov al, 1       ;system call number (sys_exit)
int 0x80        ;call kernel

section .data

msg db  'test',0xa  ; string
len equ $ - msg         ;length of   string
```

Comment: hmm, as it seems to me, you overwrite the contents of ecx.

Comment: `ecx` can't be both `10` and `msg` at the same time.

Comment: I have changed counter to be cl and used JNZ but now it became endless loop

Comment: `cl` is the low 8 bits of `ecx`. Use `esi` or `edi`.

Comment: Thank you all. Now it works. Do you think if there are any null bytes if so how can I get rid of them?

Comment: The usual trick is to use `xor` to zero registers and `call`/`pop` to get the address of the string.

Comment: *"Do you think if there are any null bytes"* - while *thinking* about it is often good mental exercise and you can probably avoid some of them already while writing the code, you don't need to rely on that. Use the "listing-file" option of assembler to see yourself which instruction generates which machine code, and where the zero bytes come from. (but if this is supposed to be exploit-like payload, then get also rid of sections like `.data`, that's not available in exploit world, i.e. learn also techniques how to provide constant data and where to get writeable memory for buffers, etc..)

Comment: but before learning the subtleties of exploit-like machine code, maybe put some more effort into assembly basics, like something you are currently doing, but somewhat more complex tasks, not bothering about zero bytes yet... Because learning both assembly basics and exploit techniques at the same time seems to me like needlessly too much. You can't skip asm basics anyway, so I would focus on that first. Also learn to use debugger, the original problem of your question would/should be easy to track in debugger, so practice that too.

Comment: Your code now depends on the upper 3 bytes of EAX being zero before your code runs.  That will be true in `_start` in a static executable, but generally not a safe assumption anywhere else.  And it's not self-correcting: a bad call number will return `-ENOSYS` and then you'll only replace the low byte of that, resulting in the same error.  Also, IDK why you're using 16-bit partial registers, that just takes extra code-size and operand-size prefixes.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if my answer will be very helpful but I did create a loop that runs 10 times which is a bit different that yours.  This is 64-bit code for Linux, unlike the question which uses 32-bit system calls.

```
global _start

section .text

_start:
    mov rbx, 10

loop:
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, msg
    mov rdx, msglen
    syscall
    dec rbx
    jnz loop
    
    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall

section .rodata
msg: db "Hello", 10
msglen: equ $ - msg
```